# Really weird behaviour when printing a date with php and drupal

Tags: php, drupal, time

So i'm just trying to print day month and year (not printing actually, i'll compare then with some dates that are in the database, but printing is testing), so my code looks like this:

`print($now = format_date(time(), "custom", "Ymd"));`

print('   ');

print( substr($now, 0, 4));  //year

print('   ');

print(substr($now, 4, 6));  //month

print('   ');

print(substr($now, 6, 8));  //day

I'm executing this on the Execute PHP Code within Devel module on a drupal website.
 This is what i get:

`20101029   2010   1029   29`

So format_date is working, year and day are alright, but what about the month? why does it print 4 chars, and not 2 as specified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP's substr is `string substr  ( string $string  , int $start  [, int $length  ] )`

So your code should read as:

```
print(substr($now, 0, 4)); //year

print(' ');

print(substr($now, 4, 2)); //month

print(' ');

print(substr($now, 6, 2)); //day
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Answer (score 1):

`substr` accepts $string, $start, and an optional $length. Try using 2 instead of 6 in both month and day.

Comment: oh, it's length, not end position